# Implementation of factory design pattern missing link

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I've read the following article in **[this link](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html)**.

Please refer to section **Class Registration - avoiding reflection** only.

In this example I cannot get the meaning of the following code line:

```
static
{
    ProductFactory.instance().registerProduct("ID1", new OneProduct());
}
```

The issues that are not clear to me:
1.Where is the method instance() defined?

2.Is instance method should be static, if so how its implementation will look a like?
(`return this` isn't possible through static method)

***Please stick to the given example unless it is wrong, I'm trying to focus on one  factory "recipe"**.

Comment: Just a suggestion - Please learn about `static` methods, and how they are invoked, before jumping into factories.

Comment: The ProductFactory, in this example; seems to be implemented using the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: @JBNizet: Do you think implementing factory as singelton pattern is always necessary, if not do you know how to refactor the given example to work properly(Without factory singelton)?

Comment: No, it's not always necessary. Patterns are used, and adapted, to solve specific problems. Recommending a solution without knowing the problem is something I won't do.

Comment: @JBNizet: Ok, so can you give me an example of when a given factory   should have some instances of it, I don't see the need for this situation.

Comment: @RohitJain: Can you specify more exactly what is the mistake I made regarding static method in the description above?

Comment: You often want a single factory, that creates many instances of the product. The singleton pattern allows having a single factory instance and access it from anywhere. (but it has serious downsides too, especially regarding testability).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am trying to answer your questions below:

> 1.Where is the method instance() defined?

The method is defined in the class `ProductFactory`, which is obvious.

> 2.Is instance method should be static, if so how its implementation will look a like?

Yes, it should be `static`. Please have a look at the definition of class `ProductFactory` and `instance()` method below:

```
public class ProductFactory extends Factory
{
    private static ProductFactory _instance;
    private HashMap m_RegisteredProducts = new HashMap();

    public static synchronized ProductFactory instance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new ProductFactory();
        return _instance;
    }

    public void registerProduct(String productID, Product p)    {
        m_RegisteredProducts.put(productID, p);
    }

    public Product createProduct(String productID){
        ((Product)m_RegisteredProducts.get(productID)).createProduct();
    }
}
```

Comment: So I guesss in this example you implementated factory as singleton(double check lock version) pattern?
By the way ,what is the difference if I will choose `synchronized` over `this` instead `ProductFactory.class`?

Comment: Please look at remarks of this double check lock in C# ,it said that it don't work in java without volatile, did you understand it? Link: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx (Version 3)

Comment: What do you say about the volatile need?

Comment: I was trying to say that if you use `double-checked locking`, you have to declare the instance as `volatile`. And it should not be used prior to `J2SE 5.0`, as it is vulnerable to subtle bugs. The above version is simpler and cleaner than `double-checked locking`.